# How to create a default body for a Retrofit call directly in the interface?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I would like to add a default body to a single Retrofit call inside the interface I made.

Let's say I have a Retrofit interface such as:

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.*

interface ExampleAPI {

    @POST
    fun makeRequest(): Call<SomeResponse>
}
```

And I would like to add a default body to the request with fields such as:

```
param_one: j32n4n4jt
param_two: k23n45k43t
```

I am aware I can wrap the generated function and inject the body via:

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.*

interface ExampleAPI {

    @POST
    fun makeRequest(@Body body: Map<String, String>): Call<SomeResponse>
}
```

or I can make a `if` check in an interceptor.

However, is it possible to implement this directly in the interface, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Generic Request:**

```
open class CommonRequest(
        @Ignore
        @SerializedName("param_one") val param_one: String = "j32n4n4jt",    
    @Ignore
        @SerializedName("param_two") val param_two: String = "j32n4n4jt"
)
```

**Actual Request:**

```
data class Request(
        @SerializedName("name") val name: String = "Andrew",

) : CommonRequest()
```

**Usage:**

```
interface ExampleAPI {
        @POST
        fun makeRequest(@Body request: Request): Call<SomeResponse>
    }
```